# Windows 8 Storage Pool in "Unrecognized Configuration", but Appears Healthy

Tags: windows-8, storage, storage-pool

I recently had a crash on my machine running W8 Pro x64. When I rebooted, my storage pool was offline, and I got a message stating that I had "Drives in an unrecognized configuration". However, it didn't list any disks that were in an unrecognized configuration.

I rebooted the machine, and the pool was automatically back online. I checked the GUI in the control panel, and it was still showing the same message. However, in powershell, the pool appears healthy. ([See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra0p8.jpg))

At this point, it seems like the pool is healthy, control panel just isn't being updated. So far, I've also tried re-scanning for hardware changes in Device Manager, re-scanning the disks from Disk Management and restarted many times. The behavior is still exactly the same after several days. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: how much data do you have in the pools? have you tried just deleting it all and starting over?

Comment: @bbodenmiller I actually ended up "refreshing" my PC. I think this may be a bug; there seem to be others with the same issue. I made a thread on MSDN that seems to have some possible solutions: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itprogeneral/thread/cac04ebf-8d01-4d6d-9d09-377750446f3b/